# Socket Hang up issue

Tags: appium-android, appium-java

Below are the logs:

```
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at UIA2Proxy.command (C:\Users\aarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\jsonwp-proxy\proxy.js:274:13)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.commands.getDevicePixelRatio (C:\Users\aarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\commands\viewport.js:14:10)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.fillDeviceDetails (C:\Users\aarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.js:244:28)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.createSession (C:\Users\aarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.js:230:7)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AppiumDriver.createSession (C:\Users\aarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:387:35)
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[31m500[39m [90m12195 ms - 1315[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
[debug] [35m[Instrumentation][39m io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:
Test case skipped
Test case skipped
Test case skipped

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 5
===============================================
```